# Olive Garden ‘Spicy Calabrian Chicken’ Recipe

Tags: restaurant-mimicry

I recently had Olive Garden’s ‘Spicy Calabrian Chicken’. They were spicy chicken tenders. They were great. Lots of heat, but I could still taste all the flavors and the heat dissipated, leaving me craving more.

Does anyone, especially anyone whose had it, know how to make this dish?

Thanks.

Edit: a couple of people seem confused and think I duplicated my question. I've gotten fussed at before on these forums for asking multiple question in one post. This question was about a recipe using a pepper. My other question is about identifying a pepper.. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of chili in Olive Garden ‘Calabrian Chicken’](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/what-type-of-chili-in-olive-garden-calabrian-chicken)

Comment: Not “possible” — same question asked by same person.

Comment: @Fabby It's not a duplicate question. One asks to identify the pepper and one asks for a recipe.

Comment: @Dalton unfortunately, we are not a recipe sharing site.  You can ask questions about ingredients or techniques, but we avoid recipes.

Comment: @moscafj : restaurant mimicry questions *are* allowed.  There's even a tag for them.  "what can I make using (ingredient)" or "does anyone have any recipes to make (generic dish)" are the ones that aren't allowed, because those don't have a definite answer.

Comment: @moscafj : and they're also frowned upon when you can easily find it w/ google, but it's a new enough recipe that it's not yet up at https://olivegardenathome.blogspot.com/

Comment: @Joe recipe comprehension and improvement are on topic.  "Do you have a recipe for..." is not on topic.  If the OP wants to give a starting point, and ask for improvements, that would work.  But my interpretation of the policy is that "does anyone know how to make this" is a recipe request.  That's why voted to close.